# Javascript websocket won't stay open?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm creating a javascript WebSocket chat room, but immediately after opening, it closes again. The code is pretty long for an online forum, but if you need it I'll be happy to give it to you. I'm also using chrome.
Here's the code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  socket.send("alert('" + username + " has disconnected from the server.')");
  socket.close();
}
var username = prompt("Enter your name (It name will be displayed to others)")
var socket = new WebSocket("MY_WEBSOCKET_URL");
socket.onopen = function() {
  socket.send("otherusers();");
  alert("Connected to server. Press 'esc' to disconnect. Type 'send' to send something.");
  alert("The users on this server will be displayed shortly (if any)")
  socket.send("alert('A new user has connected with the username " +
    username + ".')")
};
socket.onclose = function() {
  alert("Disconnected from server.")
}
socket.onerror = function(e) {
  alert("There was a server error: " + e.data);
}
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
  eval(e.data);
  //create history
  save(e.data);
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", keydown);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyup);

var s = false;
var ee = false;
var n = false;

function keydown(e) {
  //send
  if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    s = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 69) {
    if (s == true) {
      ee = true;
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 78) {
    if (ee == true) {
      n = true;
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    if (n == true) {
      s = false;
      e = false;
      n = false;
      var message = prompt("What message would you like to send? (Type 'Stop' to send nothing)");
      send(message);
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 192) {
    var messages = document.getElementsByClassName("ALINTIOKNALSFJI");
    for (var i = 0, max = messages.length; i < max; i++) {
      messages[i].setAttribute("style", "color: black; background-color: white;");
    }
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    socket.send("alert('" + username + " has disconnected from the server.')");
    socket.close();
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", keydown);
    window.removeEventListener("keyup", keyup);
  }
}

function keyup(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 192) {
    var messages = document.getElementsByClassName("ALINTIOKNALSFJI");
    for (var i = 0, max = messages.length; i < max; i++) {
      messages[i].setAttribute("style", "color: transparent; background-color: transparent;");
    }
  }
}

function send(message) {
  if (message !== "Stop") {
    socket.send("alert('Message recieved from " + username + ": " + message + "');");
    save("alert('Message sent: " + message + "');");
  }
}

function otherusers() {
  socket.send("alert('User on server: " + username + "');")
}

function save(message, float) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = message;
  if (!float) {
    float = "left";
  }
  p.setAttribute("style", "color: transparent; z-index: 1000000; background-color: transparent; float: " + float + ";");
  p.setAttribute("class", "ALINTIOKNALSFJI")
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
at WebSocket.socket.onmessage (/hackertools/chat.js:20:10)
```

FYI this is a bookmarklet.

Comment: yup we will need that code, stripped down to relevant parts of course (client and server). When you say disconnect does it connect at all or is it a timeout or disconnect after some time 60sec etc, both could be diff issues.

Comment: It does connect, because there's a socket.onopen function that fires. But then it runs the socket.close function when the onopen is finished.

Comment: error is from `eval(e.data);`, `e.data`'s contents is not js

Comment: I don't see what you mean. I'm doing this where there's nobody else on the server.

Comment: why is eval there?

Comment: For when people respond. It will send this "alert('message recieved from:" + username + ": " + message + "');");

Comment: guess username has a `'` in it then?

Comment: You really should not be calling eval, especially when other users have control of what gets sent through.

Comment: Nevermind. It's an error from the websocket provider. It says this: {"info":"V2 is taken down, use V3"}. I guess I'll 'use V3' and it should fix. Thanks!